# Highcharts - show only hours and minutes in xAxis

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to bring highcharts to show only hours and minues in xAxis, presently it's showing the full timestamp including the date. I am using the following code:

```
var chartT = new Highcharts.Chart({
  chart:{ renderTo : 'chart-temperature' },
  title: { text: 'Temperatur' },
  series: [{
    showInLegend: false,
    data: IstTemp
  }],
  plotOptions: {
    line: { animation: false,
      dataLabels: { enabled: true }
    },
    series: { color: '#059e8a' }
  },
  xAxis: { 
    type: 'datetime',
    dateTimeLabelFormats: { minute: '%H:%M' },
    categories: reading_time
  },
  yAxis: {
    title: { text: 'Temperatur (Celsius)' }
  },
  credits: { enabled: false }
});
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Hi @flohse, Please provide me with the result of `IstTemp` and `reading_time` variables.

Comment: Hi ppotaczek, they are both arrays. IstTemp is an array of float temperature values, reading_time an string array of timestams like "2021-02-12 14:35:52".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `datetime` and `category` axis type at the same time. As a solution you can:

1. Use `datetime` axis and preprocess your data to the format: `[timestamp, y]`

---

```
var IstTemp = [11.6, 12.5];
var reading_time = ["2021-02-12 14:35:52", "2021-02-12 14:38:52"];

var seriesData = IstTemp.map(function(dataEl, index){
    return [new Date(reading_time[index]).getTime(), dataEl];
});
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/7gdvzfo6/

---

2. Use categories with modified string

---

```
var IstTemp = [11.6, 12.5];
var reading_time = ["2021-02-12 14:35:52", "2021-02-12 14:38:52"];

var processedCategories = reading_time.map(function(dateStr){
    return dateStr.split(' ')[1].split(':').slice(0, 2).join(':');
});
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/2udw738c/

Comment: Thank you. Using the .map function looks really elegant. In the meantime I found a solution with preprocessing the data in PHP: 
for ($i = 0; $i < count($IstTemp); $i++) {
    $temp[] = "[".$reading_time[$i].", ".$IstTemp[$i]."]";
}
$IstTemp = "[".implode(", ", $temp)."]";
unset($temp);
Sorry for the poor formatting. Code formatting seems not to work in comments.